# Swift framework with a C lib inside: Got segmentation fault during working with C types

Tags: ios, c, swift, segmentation-fault, pjsip

I'm building swift wrapper for [PJSIP](https://www.pjsip.org) C lib.
I faced with a strange behaviour of memory alloc/free.

1. This func produces seg fault error [old plain NULL pointer]:

- `pjsua_msg_data`  is a C struct

```
    static func makePj(fromHeaders headers: [SipHeader],
                       pool: inout UnsafeMutablePointer<pj_pool_t>) -> pjsua_msg_data {
        var msgData = pjsua_msg_data()
        pjsua_msg_data_init(&msgData)

        pj_list_init(&msgData.hdr_list)

        for header in headers {
            let pjHeader = header.toPj(pool: &pool)
            pj_list_push_back(&msgData.hdr_list, pjHeader)
        }

        return msgData
    }
```

2. This implementation works (difference is that `msgData` as inout param)

```
    static func makePj(fromHeaders headers: [SipHeader],
                       msgData: inout pjsua_msg_data,
                       pool: inout UnsafeMutablePointer<pj_pool_t>) {
        pjsua_msg_data_init(&msgData)

        pj_list_init(&msgData.hdr_list)

        for header in headers {
            let pjHeader = header.toPj(pool: &pool)
            pj_list_push_back(&msgData.hdr_list, pjHeader)
        }
    }
```

3. Usage

```
        var msgData = pjsua_msg_data()

        var pool = try API.shared.createMemPool("pool", block: 4096, increment: 1024)
        defer { try? API.shared.releaseMemPool(pool) }

        if !headers.isEmpty {
            // - usage of working implementations
            //MessageData.makePj(fromHeaders: headers,
            //                   msgData: &msgData,
            //                   pool: &pool)

            // - seg fault implementation usage
            msgData = MessageData.makePj(fromHeaders: headers,
                                         pool: &pool)
        }

        try callPJSUA {
            pjsua_call_make_call(accountId,
                                 &uriStr,
                                 &callSetting,
                                 nil,
                                 &msgData,
                                 &callId)
        }
```

Little bit about framework:

- it's a just Swift wrapper under C lib.
- This framework then linked to the iOS app

Question:

- I don't understand why inout param works but returning value doesn't.
- Can I change this swift compiler behaviour? Build settings or smth else ?

Exception:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4365074432
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                   1042dc000-1056ec000 [ 20.1M] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...app/CallScape
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [2095]


Thread 11 name:   Dispatch queue: working.queue
Thread 11 Crashed:
0   SDK                                0x10d3f3f28 pjsip_hdr_clone + 36
1   SDK                                0x10d6d7454 pjsua_msg_data_clone + 280
2   SDK                                0x10d6d7454 pjsua_msg_data_clone + 280
3   SDK                                0x10d6cc4c8 pjsua_call_make_call + 1276
4   SDK                                0x10d38a710 specialized CallAPI.make(_:destinationURI:setting:headers:) + 1268
5   SDK                                0x10d389de8 protocol witness for CallAPI.make(_:destinationURI:setting:headers:) in conformance API + 12
6   SDK                                0x10d39c8a8 Call.make(to:setting:headers:) + 152
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why in the first implementation of the method (the one supposed to return a value) there is not this call: `pj_list_init(&msgData.hdr_list)` before the for loop?

Comment: Methods are equally. it's just copy-paste issue

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't explain exactly why is this a problem, but I'm sure that problem is in reference area. So when you pass msgData as inout parameter, you working with the same entity. And when you create it inside function, you assigning new value to existing value.
When you working in terms of C this is not just simple as in Swift.